# How to find index of parenthesis indexOf - confusion, Eclipse bug or feature

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I want to find position `in(` position within string, but I can not explicitly write:

```
int index = valueOf("in(");
```

because I get error of `non closed group ( java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException  Unclosed group).` If I escape parenthesis it will not find index of `in(`, but `in\(`

```
int index = value.indexOf("in\\(");
```

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT:**
I indeed made an mistake in forming the question. In my code i use indexOf but the real problem was an String.split. But when I got PatternSyntaxException I somehow went to line where indexOf was, thus I started to fixing the issue in wrong place. When I
escaped ( then indexOf did not find the "\(".

What I got confused and felt like loosing ground was what the eclipse did, then I post stackoverflow, what I do:

```
 String value = "in(test";
 String[] arr = value.split("in\\(");
```

so I have arr = {"","test"} as below:
[image]

**but why? why I see value:** 
[image]

Why in array elements string value is shown as original string? Is it bug or feature?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. `String#indexOf()` doesn't use regexp. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you can.

Comment: Your exception appears to be occurring elsewhere.

Comment: Add some context or post the stack trace.  I suspect the stack trace does not include the line of code you mention here.

Comment: good you accepted an answer, but what was the problem actually?

Comment: @Bozho: Apparently `valueOf()` did something completely different and/or he completely misinterpreted the problem. Who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.indexOf` does not take a regex. You should be able to use:

```
int index = value.indexOf("in(");
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.indexOf` essentially calls,

```
static int indexOf(char[] source, int sourceOffset, int sourceCount, char[] target, int targetOffset, int targetCount, int fromIndex);
```

and this doesn't use regular expression. It basically does a String search....

Therefore,

```
int index = value.indexOf("in(");
```

will return you the first occurrence index (from position 0) where `in(` occurs, else a `-1`.